# 500 Error: Connection closed (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Здравствуйте! Если подержать вкладку с сайтом на `node.js` открытой достаточно долго (~ 30 мин), а затем обновить, то я наблюдаю 500 ошибку, а именно Connection closed.
В качестве БД использую `Mongodb`. В качестве библиотеки для работы с ней — `Mongoose`. Сессии храню в БД с помощью библиотеки `connect-mongo` (`github`).

Подозреваю, что ошибка именно в `connect-mongo` (возможно есть более удачное сочетание `express + mongoose + sessions`).

Время жизни сессии ~ пол месяца (в базе данных) и до закрытия браузера у клиента.

Answer (score 1):

У `Express` есть свой `middleware` для работы с кукисами [`cookieParser() & cookieSession()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession)

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('секретный вопрос'));
app.use(express.session({
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: { maxAge : 3600000 } //время сессии - 1 час
}));
```

Ну а поскольку `Express` бежит поверх `Connect`, то читать [тут](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html)